# How do I add a UILabel for every song?

Tags: ios, swift

I can currently get whatever song is playing, and get a UILabel of one song's information, but when the song changes, the new song's information is not added to a new cell in a uitable. How do I get the new songs info to be added to new cells, every time a new song is played?

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "getNowPlayingItem", name: MPMusicPlayerControllerNowPlayingItemDidChangeNotification, object: nil)
    musicPlayer.beginGeneratingPlaybackNotifications()

    playButton = UIButton()
    let image = "playbutton.png"
    playButton.setImage(UIImage(named:image), forState: .Normal)
    playButton.addTarget(self, action: "play:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

func getNowPlayingItem() {
    if let nowPlaying = musicPlayer.nowPlayingItem {
        let title = nowPlaying[MPMediaItemPropertyTitle] as? String
        let artist = nowPlaying[MPMediaItemPropertyArtist] as? String
        let album = nowPlaying[MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTitle] as? String
        println("Song: \(title)")
        println("Artist: \(artist)")
        println("Album: \(album)")
        println("\n")


        self.add = [Play(name: "\(title!)\n\(artist!)\n\(album!)")]
        self.table.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        self.table.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0

    }


}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.add.count
    //return count of objects in array
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell: UITableViewCell = self.table.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! UITableViewCell
    var play: Play

    play = add[indexPath.row]

    cell.textLabel?.text = play.name

    cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 3;
    cell.textLabel?.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping


    playButton.tag = indexPath.row


    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can register for MPMusicPlayerControllerNowPlayingItemDidChangeNotification notification as detailed in https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Audio/Conceptual/iPodLibraryAccess_Guide/UsingMediaPlayback/UsingMediaPlayback.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008765-CH100-SW1

And then in the notification selector, call getNowPlayingItem to add the new song to your table.

You also have to create a new Play object with the new song info and add it to your self.add array.

```
let name = title + "\n" + artist + "\n" + album + "\n";
self.add.append(Play(name: name));
```

Comment: I already did that, but another label is not being added, look at the updated version.

Comment: You have to call reloadData on the table after you add an item

Comment: reloadData replaces one uilabel with the new song, but I want to add a new uilabel for each song in a new cell.

Comment: Instead of self.add = [Play(name: "\(title!)\n\(artist!)\n\(album!)")], you should be adding the new Play object to the self.add array.

Comment: I don't have a new Play object

Comment: I'm no swift expert but should be self.add.append(Play(name: "\(title!)\n\(artist!)\n\(album!)"))

Comment: That worked, but now I need to add a play button to each cell, I have updated my code with what I have tried, but nothing is working.

Comment: That is a different question. Please mark my answer as correct if I answered it and post another question.